# Microservices connection through message queues for web scraping pipeline applications

Tags: web-scraping, redis, microservices, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I would like to implement a microservices architecture for a Steam data scraper for academic purposes.
Currently, I have a load balancer/reverse proxy serving requests for 3 different services:

- Client: serves the content of a web application useful to call API functions and give a dashboard of different stats;
- Extractor: acts as a reverse proxy to the actual Steam web API which data will be extracted by;
- Computer: calls a separate server which can do advanced computation over the data extracted by my reverse proxy.

The user is meant to choose whether to extract data and view it as-is or send it to the computation service to retrieve a more advanced result.

Anyway, I still have a lot of doubts over the architecture design. I would like to use some message broker and cache service like Redis in order to both send the extracted data directly to the computation service (if requested) and cache some completed computations avoiding multiple calls to the Computer database, but I can't figure out a good design for this.

I tried to design it in a few ways. First, I thought that when the data is gotten by the Extractor and the user wants some extra computation on it, the Extractor itself could send it over a publisher/subscriber channel to let the Computer consume it and return the Extractor a result, which would be then sent back to the client. Also I was thinking about making the Computer itself send back the result directly to the Client, but it doesn't look promising in terms of security and data flow clarity.
Also I considered that the Extractor itself may be useless, but I still would like to use a message broker to let a few microservices communicate with each other, as a test of my knowledge of such systems.

The final result I would achieve is a sort of "pipeline" of tasks, each one executed by a different microservice (each service lies in a Docker container, but this isn't part of the problem).

Does someone have tips or experience in creating such architectures? What would you improve about what was discussed?